# Having a hard time with live-debian on USB

Tags: debian, liveusb

I already tried everything.... I download the file from this link: http://live.debian.net/cdimage/release/current/i386/usb-hdd/debian-live-6.0.6-i386-kde-desktop.img

and then I dd the image to my USB but when I boot with it, it gives me some error messages and quits to prompt. The error messages are:

*Can't start Hardware abstraction layer - please ensure dbus is running

Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon failed!

startpar:service(s)returned failure: kerneloops... failed!*

even testing the .img with Qemu I have these errors. Anyone would lend a hand here? Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Submit a bug about it and try another iso file. Have you tried iso-hybrid? Have you tried images with different desktop environments?